# How to reset animation state?

Tags: android, android-animation

When I set :

```
animationSet.setFillAfter(true);
```

The view holds the animated state there after. But before doing another animation, I need to reset the state to the old one. What I need is something like :

```
animationSet.resetFillAfter(true);
```

How can I achieve this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can call yourView.clearAnimation()